# Access a property of an Annotated type hint in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to access some property of an Annotated type hint but I don't know how to do it.
My code is the following :

```
from typing import Annotated

@dataclass
class B:
    x: str

@dataclass
class A:
    y: Annotated[str, B(x="foo")]

a = inspect.get_annotations(A, eval_str=True)
```

I want to be able to get my B instance to print some documentation to my user for example.
But I get a stringify version of the object.
I want to get something like that :

```
print(A.[my second type hint].x)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what the [`__metadata__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) attribute is for; it is a tuple consisting of all arguments you passed to `Annotated` except for the first.

```py
metadata = inspect.get_annotations(A)['y'].__metadata__

print(metadata)
# (B(x='foo'),)

print(metadata[0])
# B(x='foo')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I couldn't find the python documentation associated ! thank you :)